# Mapbox OfflineRegionObserver listener unregister

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am trying to implement offline region download. I am using the `OfflineRegionObserver` to listen to the changes in the offline region. The documentation says the observer gets notified when there is any change in the region status. My use case is I want to unregister form this listener when the user presses cancel. Bu I can't find any explicit way to unregister it. Which makes it a candidate for leaks.

```
    offlineRegion.setObserver(object : OfflineRegion.OfflineRegionObserver {
    override fun mapboxTileCountLimitExceeded(limit: Long) {
    }

    override fun onStatusChanged(status: OfflineRegionStatus?) {
    }

    override fun onError(error: OfflineRegionError?) {
    }

})
```

Now how can I unregister form this listener when I want it to happen. I want the unregister to be in my control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `offlineRegion.setObserver(null)` to unregister the listener.